# how to get hidden layer output in spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

I am using spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier to train model, the last element of param layer is the classes, but I want to get the hidden layer output, So how to do? thanks

Comment: I have solved it